# Shapiro-Wilk vs Anderson Darling test for normality

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

What makes the Shapiro-Wilk test have the best power for a given significance when compared to Anderson-Darling test and other tests.

Comment: By word of mouth, I too hear S-W to be among the best normality tests and wanted to know what makes it more powerful.

Comment: @Suriya The premise of the question is false. It *doesn't* have the "best" power. It doesn't even have better power than the Anderson-Darling except by specific choices of alternative (in *this* or *this* particular circumstance it has better power, in *that* one or *that*  one it has worse power, neither is uniformly better), so you're left to make some assessment of what you think are the kinds of alternatives you think are most relevant and how much you want to weight them. Under some particular choices of alternatives, it has better power for more of them.

Comment: There are tests that under similar criteria (choose some collection of alternatives and essentially count how often each has the higher power) outperform the Shapiro-Wilk (e.g. Chen-Shapiro) but again that does not support the general claim of one being "the best". The 2011 study discussed in wikipedia looks pretty ordinary. More extensive comparisons precede it in the literature. That it got published doesn't say a great deal for the journal.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia on 'Normality tests' says [among frequentist (non-Bayesian) tests] "A 2011 study concludes that Shapiro–Wilk has the best power for a given significance, followed closely by Anderson–Darling when comparing the Shapiro–Wilk, Kolmogorov–Smirnov, Lilliefors, and Anderson–Darling tests." and provides the reference (w/ PDF). Perhaps the reference only gives results of dozens of simulations, and perhaps it answers your question more directly. That seems a good place to start.

I would be surprised if one cannot find *any* specific non-normal distribution for which A-D has higher power.